# Splitting screen horizontally on a flexible images layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for directions rather than any specific code (wich I wouldn't spit on neither ;))
I have to code a portfolio for a friend, something like the first following picture (Sorry I only had Paint on the computer I'm asking with) :

[image]
[image]

The images should either be disposed and able to stay proportional whatever the screen size is or get arranged based on the screen size. So that the screen is always full and no need to scroll in any direction.

Then, as on the second picture of the linked album...
When clicking on a picture on the start screen, I'd like to open the screen in half and display the rest of the project. The rectangle you see up the second screen is supposed to be the same as in the center of the first one, supposed again to be the name of the portfolio. Of course I should be able to close it to get back to the page showcasing all the projects.

The effect I'm looking for is something similar to the about section here, but the other way :

http://www.b--i--g.com/about/

To sum up,

1. How to dynamically layout images full screen(s).
2. How to split in half the main screen and display other things in it.

I'm guessing here there is some keys javascripts doing all the magic so, again, any leads on wich scripts to use you know of or wich html/css structure is the best suited to do that kind of things.
I just don't have, this time, the time to start over multiples times (again) and scratch all over my code trying to make a victorian chimney blow white steam.

Comment: Sorry to kinda up my post but I can't manage to find what I'm looking for. I can code but don't know enough to get the right start...

Answer (score 0):

can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://plnkr.co/ to start with.
if you have an example webpage then you can just look at its source.
To sum up,

How to dynamically layout images full screen(s). - not clear what that means but, absolute positioning + javascript 
How to split in half the main screen and display other things in it. - there are many ways to achieve that effect. in the link you sent, they are being overlapped by the middle content. image is rendered twice on either side and the middle content right half and left half of left and right image respectively.

please post a plunker to have other help you without creating the page from scratch.